# take difference between 2nd column values using awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have a data file, let's call it fileA. It has two columns and I want to take difference of 2nd column and multiply the output with 13.6 and write it down in 3rd column with top Ediff(eV) should be written.

**FileA**

```
36 -448.21483529
40 -448.23331592
44 -448.24002943
48 -448.24322255
50 -448.24407044
52 -448.24486713
.
.
.
.
```

**Desired output**

```
36 -448.21483529  Ediff(eV)
40 -448.23331592 -0.251337
44 -448.24002943 -0.0913037
48 -448.24322255 -0.0434264
50 -448.24407044 -0.0115313
52 -448.24486713 -0.010835
.
.
.
.
```

**half working solution**

after searching I found [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/395746/printing-the-difference-between-adjacent-values-in-a-column-to-a-new-column) which is able to solve my problem but I need to put units as well. Please help me with that.

`awk 'NR>1{$3=$2-p}  {p=$2} 1' FileA`           -------found solution
`awk 'NR>1{$3=($2-p)*13.6}  {p=$2} 1' FileA`    -------- multiplied with 13.6

**output after multiplying with 13.6**

```
36 -448.21483529
40 -448.23331592 -0.251337
44 -448.24002943 -0.0913037
48 -448.24322255 -0.0434264
50 -448.24407044 -0.0115313
52 -448.24486713 -0.010835
```

How to add Ediff(eV) at the top of Ediff values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk '{print $0, (NR > 1 ? ($2-p)*13.6 : "Ediff(eV)"); p=$2}' fileA

36 -448.21483529 Ediff(eV)
40 -448.23331592 -0.251337
44 -448.24002943 -0.0913037
48 -448.24322255 -0.0434264
50 -448.24407044 -0.0115313
52 -448.24486713 -0.010835
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different code between `gawk` and `mawk` pertaining to how they track `++NF`

**CODE**

```
mawk '$++NF=!_<NR?13.6*(-__+(__=$(NF-!_))):substr("Ediff(eV)",(__=$(NF-!_))~_)'

gawk '$++NF=!_<NR?13.6*(-__+(__=$NF)):substr("Ediff(eV)",(__=$NF)~_)'
```

**OUTPUT**

```
36 -448.21483529 Ediff(eV)
40 -448.23331592 -0.251337
44 -448.24002943 -0.0913037
48 -448.24322255 -0.0434264
50 -448.24407044 -0.0115313
52 -448.24486713 -0.010835
```